# Prove all diagonal elements of a symmetric matrix are different

Tags: matrix

Given a 15*15 symmetric matrix, each row containing all the numbers from 1 to 15 and each column containing all the numbers from 1 to 15, how do you go on to prove that all the diagonal elements will be different? 
I tried to prove that no two diagonal elements will be same, but couldn't come up with anything solid. Even tried it for 5*5 matrix, but nothing I could come up with to prove it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'prove' you mean demonstrate for a particular matrix, see below. If by 'prove' you mean mathematically prove, well, all diagonal matrices are symmetric matrices, and a diagonal matrix isn't required to have unique elements, so not all symmetric matrices have unique elements on the diagonal.

One way to test a particular matrix is to make a new array containing all the diagonal elements, then eliminate duplicates in that array, and test the length. Another is to take each diagonal element and compare it against those elements on the diagonal with a higher index. Here's the latter with some pseudocode using 0 based arrays

```
unique = TRUE
for i = 0 to 14 {
  value = matrix[i][i]
  for j = i+1 to 14      // doesn't loop if i+1 > 14
    if (value == matrix[j][j])
      unique = FALSE
}
```

ADDED: The OP points out I missed the restriction on the contents of each row and column! All symmetric NxN matrices consisting of N unique values with no duplicated values in each row and column must have an antidiagonal consisting of only one value, by the definition of symmetry. If N is odd, the resulting matrix has a single element that is in both the diagonal and antidiagonal (and of course, if N is even, no element is in common). Given this, you can see the diagonal values must differ in each position from the antidiagonal, except in the common element. Combine that with the requirement that each row and each column has N values, and you'll see that the diagonal element must be different for each row. This isn't formal, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Fred, though what you wrote is not exactly I am looking for. I am looking for a mathematical proof, and under the given conditions (which I specified in the opening post) the diagonals will always have  different elements. I need to prove why it is that the diagonals will have different fifteen elements from 1 to 15.

Comment: Whoopsie! Yes, I forgot about that thinking about code. I've added a little bit which I think heads in the right direction of a proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of symmetric latin squares. The first observation (which requires a short proof) is that each of the numbers 1 to 15 occur an even number of times in the off-diagonal positions. Since 15 is odd, this means that each number must occur at least once in the diagonal positions. But there are only 15 diagonal positions and so each number must occur exactly once in the diagonal positions.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume the given matrix is m * m, and we should fill the matrix with m distinct numbers: N1, N2 ... Nm.

Because each element should show up in each column/row once, for each number, it will show up n) times in the matrix.

Because it is symmetric, each number will show up x (even) times in the upper section above the diagonal or x (even) times in the lower section below the diagonal. In this way, in addition to the diagonal, each number will show up 2 * x (x is even) times in the matrix.

Therefore, if the given m is odd, each number should show up one more time in the diagonal; if the given is even, we don't require each number show up on the diagonal cause 2 * x is already even.